# Surface pro 4 - stuck on welcome screen

Tags: microsoft-surface

I'm stuck on the welcome screen "surface" with a red headband with an open lock. The real problem is that it is impossible to access uefi paramètres with the combination of volume up and power button. Would anyone have an idea of what's causing this blockage or a solution ? Any help would really be appreciated, thanks alot.

Comment: See if you can boot with a Linux boot USB ..  It is reasonable, given the age, that the main drive may have failed which is why it is stuck.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/surface-turns-on-but-shows-a-red-bar-and-an-unlocked-lock-icon-5f738e51-2bf9-47ee-ae57-cb2fd8b4db2e Are you saying that when power the laptop off and LEAVE IT OFF for a bit, then hold the volume up and tap power and keep holding volume up, you don't get into the UEFI?

Comment: Yes, tried that